# .map error en javascript

Tags: javascript, map

tengo un problema al momento de acceder a los elementos de un array en un .map, si yo hago console.log(words.map((item) => item)) en la consola de chrome, me muestr el array con sus arrays dentro, ahora adjunto fotos para que sea mas visible, el problema viene cuando quiero acceder a un elemento cualquiera dentro de cada array.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function hint() {
    const coso = words.map((item) => item.hint)
    for (let i = 0; i <= words.length; i++) {
        if (coso[count]==true) {
            words[count].hint = 'empieza por:'+words[count].letter
        }if (coso[count]==false) {
            words[count].hint = 'contiene:'+words[count].letter
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Intenta con `words.map(item=> item?.hint )` ó `words.map(item=> item?.hint || 'hay error' )`

Comment: Añade tu código como texto a la pregunta y quizás podamos ayudarte.

Comment: agregue el codigo en el que me da error, para especificar mas, yo traigo un json de una api hecha por mi, lo que pasa es que da error aun asi cuando ejecuto esa funcion en el navegador una veza cargados los daots

Comment: @Legna me podrias responser en la zona de coments? asi queda como respuesta de el problema

Comment: @Lucas Echo, :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta con `words.map(item=> item?.hint )` ó `words.map(item=> item?.hint || 'hay error' )`

> ## [`?` - Operador de Encadenamiento Opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
>
> Permite leer el valor de una propiedad ubicada dentro de una cadena de objetos conectados sin tener que validar expresamente que cada referencia en la cadena sea válida. El operador `?`. funciona de manera similar a el operador de encadenamiento `.`, excepto que en lugar de causar un error si una referencia es casi-nula (`null` o `undefined`), la expresión hace una evaluación de circuito corto con un valor de retorno de `undefined`. Cuando se usa con llamadas a funciones, devuelve `undefined` si la función dada no existe.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, era tan simple como poner un ?, gracias legna, no sabia que en javascript podias hacer eso